# FileReaders readLine return always null JAVA

Tags: java, file, filereader

Writing a program in java I'm trying to read the content of a file which is treated as a storage. I have a function to modify the amount of an object in the store, which is organized with one line per product, where the first word is the prodCode, and the second is the amount of it. 
This is the function:

```
public static void modifyAmount(String prodCode, String newAmount){
    try{
        File magazzino = new File("Magazzino.txt");
        BufferedReader fromFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Magazzino.txt"));
        FileWriter toFile = new FileWriter(magazzino);
        String oldContent="";
        String line;
        String lineToReplace = prodCode + " " + amountRequest(prodCode);
        String newLine = prodCode + " " + newAmount;

        while((line = fromFile.readLine()) != null){
            oldContent = oldContent + line + "\n";
            System.out.println("leggendo " + line);
        }
        System.out.println(oldContent);
        String newContent = oldContent.replaceAll(lineToReplace, newLine);
        toFile.write(newContent);

        toFile.close();
        fromFile.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the result of it is that it won't enter the while cycle because the first readLine result null, though the file is correctly formatted, the 'amountRequest' function works properly and the input is correct.

Magazzino.txt:

```
1 12
3 25
4 12
```

Answer (score 3):

You're probably having trouble because you're trying to read and write the file at the same time, with different file handles.  I'd suggest reading the file first, then closing the FileReader, then creating a FileWriter to write to it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that before you have read the contents of the file, you are creating an instance of FileWriter which will clear the file.

`FileWriter toFile = new FileWriter("Magazzino.txt");` will clear the file

The solution is to just create the instance of FileWriter after you are done reading the file.

```
public static void modifyAmount(String prodCode, String newAmount){
    try{
        File magazzino = new File("Magazzino.txt");
        BufferedReader fromFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Magazzino.txt"));
        String oldContent="";
        String line;
        String lineToReplace = prodCode + " " + amountRequest(prodCode);
        String newLine = prodCode + " " + newAmount;

        while((line = fromFile.readLine()) != null){
            oldContent = oldContent + line + "\n";
            System.out.println("leggendo " + line);
        }
        fromFile.close();

        System.out.println(oldContent);
        String newContent = oldContent.replaceAll(lineToReplace, newLine);

        FileWriter toFile = new FileWriter(magazzino);
        toFile.write(newContent);

        toFile.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You open a file twice, simultaneously for reading and writing.
As soon as you do this line,

```
FileWriter toFile = new FileWriter(magazzino);
```

your file is erased. Check it yourself.
Actually, with this line you are creating a **new empty file for writing** instead of the old one.

I'd suggest read file, then close, then write.

You can also try to pen file for **append** : `new FileWriter("filename.txt", true);`
This will not erase old file, allowing you to read it. But the new data will be appended to the end, though.

If you want to use you file as a state or storage, I'd suggest to look at **sqlite**: https://www.sqlite.org/index.html